# How to print ★ symbol on SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

While Crystal reports can handle this, we are transitioning to SSRS and we need to display it on our work travelers to comply with our suppliers.  Are there alternatives to display a black star on SSRS, that can still be pulled from a text field (image not possible)?

I haven't been able to find unicode options other than this ★ (U+2605).

When the report prints, the empty square indicating "no symbol" is displayed.

Comment: Are you exporting to a specific format before printing or printing from a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Wingdings font for that.  If you paste the following character, it will appear as a black star in Wingdings:

«

Comment: This would probably have worked, but I ended up using the Segoe UI Symbol font that Jose mentioned on this site: https://www.epiusers.help/t/how-to-print-symbol-on-ssrs-report/56228